# How can I convert this assembly code from 32 bit to 64 bit?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, fasm

I have a small procedure in asm code that I use from another language through `CallWindowProc`, I have been using it for several years and it works correctly, it is in 32 bits, now I need to pass this to 64 bits but I have no idea how to do this.
I've tried several times, but I can't get it to work on 64-bit.
I am programming with FASM and I use Windows 10 64 bits.

```
Use32

;68 + Address parameters
push 0x1234567
push 0x2234567
push 0x3234567
push 0x4234567

; B8 + Address function
mov eax, 0x0D0A0E0F

; FF D0
call eax

; A3 + Address result
mov [0x0a0b0c0d], eax

; C3
ret
```

Comment: x86_64 passes arguments in registers rather than on the stack -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions.  The registers used are different for Windows vs everyone else.

Comment: What architecture and operating system are you programming for?  Please [edit] your question and add the appropriate tags.  Also mention these details in your question.  It might also help to provide a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

```
use64
enter 32,0 ; create shadow space, align stack

mov rcx, 0x1234567...
mov rdx, 0x2234567...

mov r8, 0x3234567...
mov r9, 0x4234567...

mov rax, 0x0D0A0E0F...
call rax

leave
retn
```

This assumes the calling language is treating this function as a standard Windows ABI, and no parameters need to be passed in XMM registers. Obviously, the constants will most likely need to be 64-bit to cover the general case. If there are additional parameters the stack space for them will need to be reserved beyond the shadow space, and they will need to be passed on the stack.

Comment: You usually don't want `enter`, it's very slow.  Since you're not even using RBP, you can just `sub rsp, 32+8` / `add rsp, 32+8` instead of enter/leave.

Comment: I publicly code for size because speed varies so greatly across x86 history - this is byte size and lines of code I need to type. :D